Eisenbud Section 17.5, Koszul complex is a graded complex
I apologize for the perhaps very basic question, but I am having trouble parsing Eisenbud's opening paragraph:

17.5 The Koszul Complex and the Cotangent Bundle of Projective Space
A major geometric source of the significance of the Koszul complex is its relation to the tangent bundle on projective $n$-space. We shall only sketch the connection, which belongs perhaps more to algebraic geometry than to commutative algebra. First note taht if $R$ is a graded ring and $x=(x_0,\ldots,x_n)$ is a sequence of homogeneous elements, then the Koszul complex $K(x)$ has the structure of a graded complex (that is, a complex of graded free modules where all the maps are homogeneous of degree $0$). Quite generally, if $M$ is a graded $R$-module, then since $\wedge M$ is a bigraded algebra, the Koszul complex of any homogeneous element of degree $0$ of $M$ is graded. Thus we need only regard $x$ as a homogeneous element of degree $0$ in the graded free module $M = \oplus_i R(\deg x_i)$. If all the $x_i$ have degree $1$, then we can write the $j$th termof the complex as $\wedge^j R^{\binom{n+1}{j}}(j)$.

I do not understand the sentence "note that if R is a graded ring and $x= (x_0, \cdots, x_n)$ is a sequence of homogeneous elements, then the Koszul complex K(x) has the structure of a graded complex (that is, a complex of graded free modules where all the maps are homogeneous of degree 0)."
If $R$ is a graded ring, then it is of the form $\bigoplus R_i$, and each $x_i$ belongs in some $R_{d_i}$. Then the Koszul complex $K(x)$ is
$$
0 \to R \to R^{\oplus n} \to \bigwedge^2 R^{\oplus n} \to \cdots \to \bigwedge^n R^{\oplus n} \to 0.
$$
I don't understand what the grading is on $\bigwedge^k R^{\oplus n}$, and what map is homogeneous of degree 0? The differentials? But the differentials are giving by wedging by $x = (x_1, \cdots, x_n)$. How could this possibly be a degree 0 map?
\par
I find the next sentence confusing as well. If $M$ is a graded $R$-module, then it is of the form $\bigoplus M_i$ where $R_j M_i \subseteq M_{i+j}$. How does $\bigwedge M$, which I interpret to be the exterior algebra $\bigwedge^* M$, admit a bigrading? Will it not be of the form $\bigwedge^*( M_0 \oplus M_1 \oplus M_2 \oplus \cdots)$?
Thank you for any clarification provided.

By the way, images of text are discouraged here - it's far better to write them out using mathjax so that they are accessible and searchable. I've replaced the picture with text for you this time, please keep this in mind for the future. (Also, the final symbol in the picture was a bit garbled, I made an attempt to fix it, you may wish to review that in case I got it wrong.)

Okay, got it -- thank so much, I appreciate the help!

This could be a bit clearer, and I think there is a slightly different perspective which will help this idea get across better. Recall that the Koszul complex may be equivalently defined as the total complex of the tensor product $\bigotimes\left(R\stackrel{x_i}{\to} R\right)$. If $R$ is graded and all the $x_i$ are homogeneous, we can make $R\stackrel{x_i}{\to} R$ graded pretty easily: if $\deg x_i = d_i$, then we can rewrite $R\stackrel{x_i}{\to} R$ as $R(-d_i)\stackrel{x_i}{\to} R$ since the twist by $d_i$ is an isomorphism on the underlying ring to get that complex to be graded. After recognizing that the tensor product of graded things is again graded, we can now interpret the Koszul complex as a graded complex.
